# Automatically style each link on a page differently using nth-child/type?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to add a special style to specific links on my page but I don't want to add a separate class to each link that might appear on a page. I want every 8n+1 (through 8n+8) href to be a different color.  So far it's not working using nth-child or nth-of-type. I assume this is because the links are in paragraphs and lists, etc., so they aren't recognized as direct or even sibling selectors, even though the parent selector I'm prefixing it with is the parent.

Here's my CSS:

```
#main > a:nth-of-type(8n+1) {
    color: #ef9623 !important;
}

#main > a:nth-of-type(8n+2) {
    color: #dab828 !important;
}
```

etc. I've tried it with ~ and without either one. None of them seem to work. Is it likely that this will require jquery instead of CSS?

Comment: add your code sample html + css

Comment: Please add your HTML structure to the question.

Comment: You might just need to remove the direct descendant indicator (`>`).

Comment: The html structure isn't relevant. The point is that I want to target all href elements, on a page where the body has the id of main, and regardless of whether they're in paragraphs, li elements or whatever. Apparently that's not possible.

Comment: Also, as mentioned above, I have tried it without the direct descendant indicator. I have also tried with the child indicator (~). And I've tried it with neither at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the links are in paragraphs, than the css selectors need to appropriate. Assuming you have this html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p><a href="#">foo</a></p>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

To style the links you need to select like this:

```
div.wrap p:nth-child(8n+2)  a { … }
```

Because the paragraphs are the children to count.

**EDIT** If some of the links are in paragraphs and some not, you need to create a more flexible selector. One thing you can do is to set a class for each child of the first level like:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p class="countable"><a href="#">foo</a></p>
    <div class="countable"><a … </a></div
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Than you can select like: `div.wrap .countable:nth-child(…) a { … }`

I am unsure if even: `div.wrap > *:nth-child(…) a { … }` could work, but I am pretty sure…

[PROOF](https://jsfiddle.net/owxgqj8x/)

**EDIT #2**

In fact the `nth-child` pseudo selector will only work for direct children (`>`), to style each 8th link, no matter where in the HTML you will need to use JS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('#main a'), function (idx, e) {
        // % the nth child 
        if (idx % 8 == 0) { 
            //do something with the element
            $(e).html('eighth');
        }
    });
});
```

This way each link, in appearance in the DOM, will be added to a list and styled if `idx % nthChild == 0`.

**EDIT #3**

Finally, the whole thing can be simplified to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('#main a'), function (idx, e) {
        $(e).addClass('nth-' + (idx % 8));
    });
});
```

this will add a class to each link starting from `nth-0` going to `nth-7` and starting again until all elements are processed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm suspecting that's the issue. And some of the links aren't in paragraphs, some are in li elements, etc. I was hoping there was a way to set it up as just *any* href element on the page, regardless of what surrounding elements there are. Ah well.

Comment: Thanks, Philipp. I'm going to try the js. That seems most probable to work consistently. I'd really like to avoid extra markup if possible. I'd probably forget to add it later on, and then I'll just be annoyed trying to remember what I did to make it work. LOL

Comment: (bear with me, I'm really just learning js here) where you have "//do something with the element" above the "$(e).html('eight');", would I put something like, say "$.addClass("link-eight");" there? Or below the ".html('eight')" line? Or would I replace the "eighth" line with the addClass bit?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Philipp, this is what I ended up doing:

the js...

```
$.each($('#main .col-md-9 .entry-content a'), function (idx, e) {
    // % the nth child
    if (idx % 1 == 0 ) {
        $(e).addClass('link-one');
    }
    if (idx % 2 == 0 ) {
        $(e).addClass('link-two');
    }
    if (idx % 3 == 0 ) {
        $(e).addClass('link-three');
    }
    if (idx % 4 == 0) {
        $(e).addClass('link-four');
    }
    if (idx % 5 == 0) {
        $(e).addClass('link-five');
    }
    if (idx % 6 == 0) {
        $(e).addClass('link-six');
    }
    if (idx % 7 == 0) {
        $(e).addClass('link-seven');
    } 
    if (idx % 8 == 0) { 
        $(e).addClass('link-eight');
    }
});
```

And the CSS...

```
.link-one {
    color: #ef9623 !important;
}

.link-two {
    color: #dab828 !important;
}

.link-three {
    color: #c0d72f !important;
}

.link-four {
    color: #1bbaed !important;
}

.link-five {
    color: #aa84b5 !important;
}

.link-six {
    color: #e80783 !important;
}

.link-seven {
    color: #ef9623 !important;
}

.link-eight {
    color: #dab828 !important;
}
```

This seems to be working perfectly. I'm very happy.