# code not work - auto add class using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, jsfiddle

I get this code from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38950619/11836852) its working good u see example in Jsfiddle and press **F12** and see the console.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ohari5336/L2r8x9fh/
```

but when I set this code in my code then it's not work

````
```https://jsfiddle.net/ohari5336/9Lcy0mnf/```
````

please, anyone helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are adding class to a SVG element, and according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130050/add-class-on-svg-path-element/36150373), you can't use addClass() for this, instead, use attr('class', 'class-name').